# Debug Office add-ins in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ms-office, excel-addins, office-js

I made a manifest which points (via localhost) to files stored on my Mac. I could upload the manifest to Excel online, and it works:

[image]

Now, does anyone know how to debug the add-in in Chrome? For example, is it possible to see the JavaScript or Html files which make the add-in, and how to set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inspect the HTML, do you see the arrow pointing into the box to the left of the Elements tab? You can use that to select and inspect elements on the web page. That should help you find the HTML.

Have you tried the Sources tab? Select a script and set a break point.